# user authorisation with express.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, express

hey guys l have been trying to implement login for users but struggling on how to make the comparison in the database for name and the password so they can login with sessions but l've only managed to do this below

```
exports.userSignup = function(req, res) {
  res.render('signup');
};

exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
  req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (req.body.name && req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        // if user puts correct info the get save to database
        var newUser = {
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            confirm_password: req.body.confirm_password
        };

        // using bycrypt to store hashed passwords
        var passwordStore = bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds,     f      function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash
            bcrypt.compare(newUser.confirm_password, hash, function(err, res) {
                newUser.confirm_password = hash
                connection.query('insert into Users set ?', newUser, function(err, results) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    req.flash("success", 'Welcome', newUser.name);
                    req.session.user = newUser;
                    res.redirect('/categories');
                });
            });
        });

    } else {
        var err = new Error('All fields must be filled. ')
            // req.flash("danger", "All fields must be filled")
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err)
    }
})
```

}

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
  res.render('login')
```

}

```
exports.signIn = function(req, res, next) {
   req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query('SELECT name, email, password from Users', function(err,  rows, fields) {
        req.session.user = {
            name: req.body.name,
            password: req.body.password,
            is_admin: rolesMap[req.body.name] === "admin"
        }
        res.redirect("/categories")
    })
})
```

}`

Can someone please help me with my login because its the only thing that l'm struggling with and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be "working" code:
 1. You are fetching ALL users in the database (bad). Fix this by getting just 1 user
 2. You are doing a bcrypt.compare on a hash and plain value, which you don't need there (unessesary processing, bad). Fix this by replacing with newUser.password === newUser.confirm_password

If this last piece of code is incomplete, and you need a query / flow to authenticate a user:
 1. SELECT (your fields) FROM Users WHERE (some identifier) = (identifier from login-form)
 2. bcrypt.compare(passwordFromForm, hashFromQueryResult, setUserSession)

identifier in this case is a field in your database that is unique to this user. For example username, id, email, phone number, etc. This have to be provided in the login form. ("name" in this case) - but it has to be unique

EDIT:

Also, I would suggest replacing most of this with Passport.js